# Bash single input several times

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg

I have a script as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -stabilization-pass-1-stuff && \
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -b:v xxxxk -stabilization-pass-2-h264-pass-1-stuff && \
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -b:v xxxxk -h264-pass-2-output-stuff output.mp4
```

How can I rewrite the script so I have to provide input.mp4 and bitrate xxxxk once at start of script?

Comment: [Parameters - Linux - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-parameters.html)

Answer (score 1):

With shell variables. "Not repeating yourself" is one of the main usage cases for shell variables:

```
#!/bin/sh

file='input.mp4'
bitrate='xxxxk'

ffmpeg -i "$file" -stabilization-pass-1-stuff &&
ffmpeg -i "$file" -b:v "$bitrate" -stabilization-pass-2-h264-pass-1-stuff &&
ffmpeg -i "$file" -b:v "$bitrate" -h264-pass-2-output-stuff output.mp4
```

---

Notes:

- Your script contains no [shebang](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87600/108618). In such case [the interpreter depends on the shell you invoke the script from](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/373229/108618). In general it's not a good idea to omit shebang. I added `#!/bin/sh` for two reasons:

  1. to show how a shebang looks like;
  2. to indicate that shell variables are quite a basic concept that works in `sh`, so you can expect the same code to work in any shell that tries to be POSIX-compliant.
- [After `&&` you don't need `\` to continue in the next line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/253520/108618).
- [Quoting is important](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).